# How to store nested data in python?

Tags: python, json, data-structures, pickle

I have nested data labeled 'books' as follows,

```
book0 = {'authorId': u'4657987','bookId': u'3532901',
 'genre': u'horror','freeChapters': [[u'2015-07-03 15:14:25', u'3376'],
  [u'2015-07-03 17:52:39', u'2116'],...,[u'2015-07-26 20:08:11', u'2120'],
  [u'2015-07-27 20:12:12', u'2139']],'updateStatus': u'to be continued',
 'wordCount': u'56322'} 

book1 = {'authorId': u'3840480','bookId': u'3453158',
 'genre': u'romance','freeChapters': [[u'2015-04-07 18:58:15', u'317'],
  [u'2015-04-02 21:46:36', u'2103'],
  [u'2015-04-03 13:02:17', u'2416'], ...,
  [u'2015-07-24 00:07:43', u'2195']],'updateStatus': u'completed',
 'chargedChapters': [[u'2015-07-25 14:14:53', u'10'],
  [u'2015-07-26 00:07:46', u'11'],
  [u'2015-07-27 00:07:58', u'10'],
  [u'2015-07-28 00:07:52', u'10']],
 'wordCount': u'269059'}
```

...

I expect to have ~200,000 such objects, each scraped from the Internet. Given that each 'book' requires some effort and time, I would like to save them one by one. I don't think JSON allows me to do it, and I am currently using pickle. However, later I may need to reference a particular book. I am afraid that I have to unpickle over and over in order to do that. In my case, what is the best way to store these objects?

I eventually settled with line-separated JSON.

Comment: Looks pretty relational to me. Perhaps a relational database?

Comment: But please don't pickle it. It ties you to python, and even certain versions of python.

Comment: Also, 200,000 is somewhat small. If each entry is 1KB, that's 200MB. You can definitely store that in working memory, though it's _close_ to being too big.

Comment: I see. I will take a look at relational database in Wikipedia.

Comment: If you haven't used them before, consider sqlite. Python ships with it, you don't have to "manage" it as a service, but it still gets your feet wet with SQL.

Comment: Good to know that it is not too large. That means that no matter what form I save it, I can have the entire database in memory. Hopefully my laptop will not crash.

Comment: @user2864740 double check your math. I got 2GB.

Comment: I have deleted the "working memory" part to make the question more correct.

Comment: One clarification on my relational comment. This isn't hierarchical data. The structures might be nested, but it's flat. Where relational DBs struggle with hierarchies is when Books are composed of (sub) Books, and each (sub) Book is a (sub-sub) Book. Taxonomies are a good example of this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The politically correct answer is "it depends". That said, go with `JSON`.

`Pickle` is a powerful format, capable of rebuilding complex objects of rich data types. It is, however, comparatively slow, it binds you to python and is not 100% safe for untrusted data. **It offers rich typing, but not speed, portability, or safety**. It's also **not human readable**.

`XML` is an old format, and is falling out of use. It doesn't map directly to object-oriented design. Reading and writing `XML` in most modern languages is cumbersome, verbose, and produces uneasy abstractions. **There's are very few reasons to use XML today**.

`JSON` is a light-weight format of very broad adoption. It offers limited data types (dates are missing, for example). This means *stringifying* a lot of types, but also means that the format is relatively safe: untrusted data can do nothing to suprise you. It's **fast, highly portable and human-readable**. It **maps almost directly to object-oriented design**. There are **many libraries and tools for working with JSON**, which means it's **easy to convert to other formats**.

`JSON` is the default choice. Unless there are reasons to avoid it, use it. In any case, you can start with `JSON` and switch later.

Comment: JSON doesn't really map to OO design any better or worse than XML. JSON does map to lists and dictionaries, but that's not really what OO design is.

Comment: My book0 and book1 are different, since there are 'chargedChapters' in book1 which are absent in book0. I tried JSON and find that JSON decoder can not handle different objects.

Comment: @YeTian It should be able to handle it fine. What exactly is the error you get?

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo Do you mind taking a look at the edited post?

Comment: @YeTian That won't produce valid JSON; it will produce something like `{}{}`. Try `f.write(json.dumps([book1, book2]))`

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo Indeed it works, but is there a way to dump the books one by one? I have thousands of books to scrape. If my computer crashes, I would like at least to see partial progress.

Comment: @YeTian I don't think so. At that scale, I'd suggest using SQLite, where that's possible.

Comment: @YeTian you can write line-separated JSON. No need to use a single huge JSON document. Then read it by lines, parsing a document per line

Answer (score 1):

JSON. It's accepted in many languages, lightweight and will maintain this hierarchical structure that you have.

Answer (score 0):

One of the easiest things to do is try `klepto`, which provides an API to storing relational data in python.  `klepto` provides a dictionary interface to storing items in key-value pairs in a database, or in database-like storage on disk.  One of the issues you are having is storing all the books in one file.  However, if you store one entry (one book) per file, then when you want to access a book, it will be much faster.  `klepto` makes this easy for you, as you interact with a dictionary object, and it does the rest of retrieving from the correct pickled file on disk, or the object stored in the database. `klepto` is meant to make it easy to work with large data storage and retrieval for key-value pairs.  So that's the first thing you should address. `klepto` will enable you to try storing one-entry-per-file on disk, and then if you find that insufficient, it is very easy to switch the archive backend to a SQL database table (or tables).  Another choice is storage in a `hdf5` file or files.

The second thing is you'll need to see which storage format you want to use (`pickle`, `json`, etc).  `klepto` provides nearly 100 combinations of storage and encoding formats within a common interface, so you can figure out what works for you by trying it and seeing which is the most robust and fastest.  As others have suggested, I'd go with `json` if you care about security and robustness across versions of python -- and the objects you want to store are simple (and it looks like yours are). If you need to store more complex objects, like class instances or lambdas, then you might want to use `pickle` (`dill` actually) as the encoder… it will be a bit slower, but much more robust.  There are other options that are much faster than `pickle` or `json`, but are not as persistent.  Switching the encoding and storage format in `klepto` is pretty easy too.

Comment: It feels as though you tried pretty hard to shoehorn `klepto` into the conversation, almost as though you were promoting it. This is definitely nowhere near the worst examples of self-promotion we've seen on Stack Overflow, but the very least you could do is disclose that you're the author of `klepto`.

Comment: @JohnY: I didn't try hard at all. I suggested it because it's the right solution, even though it's not exactly what the OP asked.  Did I not say I'm the author?  I'm the author.  It's not self promotion… it's the right solution for what the OP needs.  I'd suggest something else if there was a better fit.

Comment: It's [official Stack Overflow policy](http://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior) to disclose product affiliations, commercial or not. It doesn't have to be obtrusively highlighted. It's enough to say something like "My `klepto` package is a good fit for these requirements because...". But it needs to be in the answer, not just a flippant remark in the comments only after someone calls you out on it. See also [this relevant question on MetaSE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57497/limits-for-self-promotion-in-answers).

Comment: Yes, I know the policy, and pretty religiously follow it.  It was an honest omission, as I stated in the comment.  You seem like you are looking for trouble, there is policy against harassment too, you know.  Maybe you want to take this into a sidebar if you still feel like you need to quote SO policy?  Otherwise, this is my last comment along this thread.